# How to make eclipse look in two diffrent places for jvm on start up

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, linux-mint, eclipse

I need to know how to make eclipse look in two locations for the jvm. I have it set one way in the .ini file but I need to be able to have it look in another place as well.

I have eclipse IDE installed on an external harddrive as well as a jvm on the same external harddrive. I have 3 computers that I want to be able to just run eclipse on, 2 ubuntu and 1 mint. I have it working with the 2 ubuntu machines but not the mint one but I know why.

When I plug the drive into  the ubuntu machines it mounts as /media/myDrive so in the .ini file for starting eclipse I can put /media/myDrive/myJvmLocation. When I plug it into the mint machine it mounts /media/userName/myDrive/. Since it puts it under a username dir it then cannot find the jvm on the harddrive.

I can manualy go in and change the loction to the jvm inside the .ini file but would rather be able to give it a list of locations. If I just list both locations it uses the last one listed and ignores the first one.

Anybody know a good work around that involves the .ini. I don't want to edit the mint machine to mount differently.

Comment: You can specify the -vm option on the command line: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Frunning_eclipse.htm

Comment: In cases such as this you/I should use a relative path instead of an absolute path.

Comment: This should not of been converted to a comment as it is the exact answer to the problem. Over moderation yet again.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure but you can try by exporting/adding both the jvm paths in environmental variables using the below command

PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:  /media/myDrive/myJvmLocation

Comment: But then I am doing something to the machines when I want the fix encapsulated on my drive so I can use any Linux machine in general.